# Synchronize output from read thread for particular write request android

Tags: android, multithreading

I have one socket opened. I created InputStream and OutputStream for same.

I have one read thread which does 1 by 1 byte reading using InputStream.

I have one function which send command to socket

For each write there is different output I received.
For example if I write command_1 then I received "abcdefghijklmabcdefghijklm"
if send command_2 then i received "12345678900987654321"

This works fine when I send command_2 after completion of command_1. but if I sent command_2 in between receiving process of command_1 then data receiving from 1 is get override.

I need some kind of synchronization. Not sure how.

Comment: Do you call flush() after you write command_1?

Comment: yes I did.... still getting same issue

Comment: still looking for answer...